# Firebase login error returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@bd27b3b

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I am creating a new user through my app using Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() and the user is being created. But when I am trying to log in again there is a firebase auth warning:

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@bd27b3b

Also when I tried to log the error it shows:

> D/Firebase: The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.

Here is the screenshot of the dependencies:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-wO7VpyjezGm59NnmE8GC7JUm14fXAYV

And here is the logcat

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1odYzcDf5mtHe7F4riTxVMZOyYOEiwGa2

Here is the code snippet of logging in the user

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mSignIn = findViewById(R.id.signin_button);
    mSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mUser = username.getText().toString().trim();
            mPass = username.getText().toString().trim();
            if (inputValidate(mUser, mPass)) {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mUser, mPass)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreen.class));
                                } else {
                                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                    Log.d("Firebase",task.getException().getMessage());
                                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    });
    signUp = findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp.class));
        }
    });
}
private boolean inputValidate(String user, String pass){
    if(user.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        username.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(pass.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        password.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Fir Signing Up  the user

```
           if(inputValidate(mEmail,mPassword,mConfPassword,mClass,mPhone,mName)){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final FirebaseAuth mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mEmail,mPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Log.d("Firebase User",task.getResult().toString());
                            FirebaseUser mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if(mUser!=null) {
                                muserId = mUser.getUid();
                            }
                            UserDetails user = new UserDetails(mName,mPhone,mClass,mEmail);
                            mProfileDatabaseReference.child(muserId).push().setValue(user);


                            Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeScreen.class);
                            i.putExtra("Name",mName);
                            i.putExtra("Email",mEmail);
                            i.putExtra("Phone",mPhone);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Sign Up failed.Please try in some time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });



}

private boolean inputValidate(String email,String pass,String cpass,String mClasss, String phone, String name ){
    if(email.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        eEmail.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    else if(pass.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ePassword.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    else if (!cpass.equals(pass)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password and Confirm Password dont match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        eConfPassword.requestFocus();
        return false;
    } else if (mClasss.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        classSpinner.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }  else if (phone.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ePhone.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }  else if (name.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter your Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        eName.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: Please put your code as code and not as image

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot accept questions here that use Google Drive to store images. Stack Overflow has its own image host and that should be preferred. That said, if these are all code, they should not be images at all - textual information should be supplied as text.

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself._

Comment: I am sorry its my first time asking question on StackOverflow. I will change the things